# Clojure cond or if?

Tags: clojure

Currently I am programming a map that will take an amount of money from one id and transfer it to another but whenever I add an if or cond statement to make sure that they have enough in their balance I keep getting a sending too many arguments error. if I use cond It says that cond requires an even number of forms. Any help would be appreciated

Code:

```
 (defn transfer[ledger from-id to-id amt]
    (dosync
        (let [from-id (get @ledger from-id)]
        (let [to-id (get @ledger to-id) ]
            (if from-id 
                (if to-id
                    (let [bal1 (get from-id :balance)]
                    (let [bal2 (get to-id :balance)]
                        (cond (< amt bal1)
                            (alter bal1 - amt)
                            (alter bal2 + amt)
                        :else "Too much"

                    )       
            nil
                nil
            ))))))))
```

Comment: there;s no need to nest the `let` expressions. You can include multiple bindings in the same `let`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about `cond` or `if`, but it's on "how to group multiple s-exps into one and evaluate them sequentially".

Use `do` as in:

```
(defn transfer[ledger from-id to-id amt]
  (dosync
   (let [from-id (get @ledger from-id)
         to-id (get @ledger to-id)]
     (if (and from-id to-id)
       (let [bal1 (:balance from-id)
             bal2 (:balance to-id)]
         (if (< amt bal1)
           (do
             (alter bal1 - amt)
             (alter bal2 + amt))
           "Too much"))))))
```

Comment: Hmm I tried adding do but I still get the too many arguments to if compiling error; Yea I need to use if-let more often but I just get stuck in a coding style and I keep forgetting to try to change it.

Comment: @TerryMasters Without touching your semantics, I've clean up the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks man that does work but now I just have to figure out why I am getting a ref cannot be cast to java.lang.number when I do it this way